# Some tokens not work with CiviRules 2.1 and E-mail API 1.17.2?

Tags: wordpress, email, civirules

I'm using WordPress 4.9.8, CiviCRM to 5.4.0, CiviRules 2.1 and E-mail API 1.17.2. I've created a Rule that send email to contact when added to a group. I've used some token here
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/#available-tokens

But only token {domain.email} and {domain.name} can show. Other tokes is empty. Is it bug?

Comment: Which tokens are you trying to use?  Some tokens are only available in particular contexts.

Comment: I've tried token {action.subscribeUrl} first and after all other token in that link.

Answer (score 2):

This might be caused by this issue: https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.emailapi/issues/10. A fix is in progress....